# Have table.el insert space after vertical separator for reStructuredText

Tags: table

I am using Emacs's `table.el` mode to fill a lot of tables in rst documents.
`table.el` is really fine to do the job, but it lacks the possibility to have one space between vertical separator and cell content.

That is, by default, it fills tables like this:

```
+-------+-----+
|content|stuff|
+-------+-----+
```

What I want to achieve is to have a one space padding before and after each separator to match the RST syntax like this :

```
+---------+-------+
| content | stuff |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: You could switch to using `orgtbl-mode`, which (according to its [docstring](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun%2Forgtbl-mode.html)) gives you "The `org-mode` table editor as a minor mode for use in other modes".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to convert table to org-mode's table, and then convert it back. Here's the code:

```el
(require 'org)

(setq save-y-or-n-p nil)

(defadvice table-re-indent (around always-yes)
  (fset 'save-y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'y-or-n-p))
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (lambda (s) t))
  ad-do-it
  (fset 'y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'save-y-or-n-p)))

(defun table-re-indent ()
  "Put the point in the table and call this function"
  (interactive)
  (org-table-create-with-table.el)
  (org-table-create-with-table.el))
```

To use it put the point in the table and call `M-x table-re-indent`.

Comment: You should use `unwind-protect` in your advice as to assure that `y-or-n-p` will always get set back to the original value.